# Configure matrix authorization plugin using Groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am learning to write the groovy script to configure matrix authorization plugin. I have written this script where only authenticated users can access Jenkins:

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.security.*
import com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.properties.AuthorizationMatrixProperty

try {
    def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
    def realm = new HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm(false)
    instance.setSecurityRealm(realm)

    def strategy = new hudson.security.GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy()
    strategy.add(Jenkins.ADMINISTER, 'authenticated')
    instance.setAuthorizationStrategy(strategy)

    instance.save()

}
catch(Throwable exc) {
    println '!!! Error configuring jenkins'
    org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StackTraceUtils.sanitize(new Exception(exc)).printStackTrace()
    println '!!! Shutting down Jenkins to prevent possible mis-configuration from going live'
    jenkins.cleanUp()
    System.exit(1)
}
```

Now, I want to configure this matrix plugin in a way that nobody can access the Jenkins settings area(even authenticated users can not access the Jenkins settings). I have done lot of research on that and not able to move forward with this. Any help/pointer will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I am have added "strategy.add(Jenkins.READ, 'authenticated')" instead of Jenkins.ADMINISTER and it works!!

Comment: You should post your finding as your answer and answer your own question.

Comment: ok. I am adding it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to that. Below is the complete code for the above requirement where I was missing Jenkins.READ.

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.security.*
import com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.properties.AuthorizationMatrixProperty

try {
    def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
    def realm = new HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm(false)
    instance.setSecurityRealm(realm)

    def strategy = new hudson.security.GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy()
    strategy.add(Jenkins.READ, 'authenticated')
    instance.setAuthorizationStrategy(strategy)

    instance.save()

}
catch(Throwable exc) {
    println '!!! Error configuring jenkins'
    org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StackTraceUtils.sanitize(new 
    Exception(exc)).printStackTrace()
    println '!!! Shutting down Jenkins to prevent possible mis-configuration from going live'
    jenkins.cleanUp()
    System.exit(1)
}
```